# CQ5 open dialog on page load

Tags: extjs, aem

I have a cq page with a component included by using `<cq:include />`

I would like to get the included **component dialog open on the page load**, rather than waiting for author to double click on the component area.

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 8):

this is something i had done when i want to open dialog

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% if (((String)properties.get(configuration.getInherited("connectedWhen", "username"), "")).trim().equals("")) { %>
CQ.WCM.onEditableReady("<%= resource.getPath() %>", function(editable){
    CQ.wcm.EditBase.showDialog(editable);
}, this);
<% } %>
</script>
```

or if you want a more clean code try this :

```
CQ.WCM.onEditableReady("<%= resource.getPath() %>", function(editable){
    CQ.wcm.EditBase.showDialog(editable);
}, this);
```

Hope it'll help.. :)

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you.